# Elasticsearch Inner com loja

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch

No meu projeto há cerca de 40.000 produtos de lojas diferentes, mas para retornar uma busca pelo *Elasticsearch*,preciso do filtro cidade e estado de onde está localizado a loja. O problema é o seguinte, se uma loja possui 10.000 produtos, eu devo colocar a localização da loja em todos os produtos, ou existe alguma forma de fazer uma espécie de inner igual o Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o elasticsearch trabalha com coleções de dados. Logo você não tem chave estrangeiras com forte integridade referencial como nos bancos relacionais. No seu caso eu colocaria o id da loja na collection para usar como chave na busca.

Comment: Mas ai que está. Não me importa a loja, mas sim a sua localização.

Comment: Vc esta usando apenas o elasticsearch? Você tem que pensar que o elasticsearch é apenas uma das ferramentas que vc tem. Você precisa relacionar os dados e não apenas guardar e consultar. Então tendo um identificador da loja vc chega na loja e pega a latitude e longitude. Pra ser sincero isso é bem relativo, de qualquer forma vai funcionar. Existem n formas de fazer isso, mas acredito que a mais modularizada seja a mais correta, vc prefere atualizar todos ou produto como uma nova localização? ou apenas um registro de Loja?